# Access token and API action

Tags: java, json, spring, api, http

I am creating a service where I get the access token and I want to perform some API action using that access token. I want the API action to be generic? Like I don't want to hard code any action in the code. I want to pass the JSON in the postman and sent the request.

RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();

```
/**
 * Method that returns a connector response value from a REST API Call.
 * 
 * @throws JsonProcessingException
 * @throws JsonMappingException
 *
 */

@Override
public String getConnectorResponse(ConnectionManager connectionManager)
        throws JsonMappingException, JsonProcessingException {
    LOGGER.debug("getConnectorResponse method called");
    String url = connectionManager.getURL();
    String httpMethodType = connectionManager.getHttpMethodType();
    HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();

    Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<>();
    String bodyType = connectionManager.getBodyType();

    LOGGER.info("Making REST call to URL: {}", url);
    LOGGER.info("HTTP Method Type: {}", httpMethodType);

    if (bodyType == "ROW") {
        headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
        LOGGER.info("Headers: {}", headers);
        LOGGER.info("Body Type: {}", bodyType);

    }
    HttpEntity<?> entity1;

    switch (bodyType) {
    case "URLENCODED":
        headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED);
        MultiValueMap<String, Object> map1 = new LinkedMultiValueMap<String, Object>();
        Map<String, String> m = connectionManager.getMap().get(0);
        for (Entry<String, String> entry : m.entrySet()) {
            map1.add(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
        }
        entity1 = new HttpEntity<MultiValueMap<String, Object>>(map1, headers);

        LOGGER.info("Headers: {}", headers);
        LOGGER.info("Body Type: {}", bodyType);
        break;

    default:
        headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        JsonNode jsonNode = mapper.readTree(mapper.writeValueAsString(connectionManager.getMap()));
        map.put("data", jsonNode);
        String authorization = connectionManager.getAuthorization();
        String scope = connectionManager.getScope();
        headers.set("Authorization", authorization);
        headers.set("scope", scope);
        LOGGER.info("Headers: {}", headers);
        LOGGER.info("Body Type: {}", bodyType);
        entity1 = new HttpEntity<Map<String, Object>>(map, headers);
        break;
    }
    String response = "";
    try {
        ResponseEntity<String> responseEntity = restTemplate.exchange(url, HttpMethod.POST, entity1, String.class);
        if (responseEntity.getStatusCode().is2xxSuccessful()) {
            response = responseEntity.getBody();
            LOGGER.debug("response from REST call: " + response);
        } else {
            LOGGER.debug("Error in REST call, status code: " + responseEntity.getStatusCode().value());
            throw new RuntimeException(
                    "Error in REST call, status code: " + responseEntity.getStatusCode().value());
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        LOGGER.debug("Error in getConnectorResponse method: " + e.getMessage());
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }

    return response;

}
```

Comment: I think your question is unclear, what exactly are you having an issue with? Are you getting a specific error?

Comment: Hi @blacktide, I am not getting any error. If you see the code above I have hard coded the " map.put("data", jsonNode);" . I am trying to insert values into ZOHO and its working because the key in JSON is "data" which I have hard coded. Now I want to insert some values into other api lets say github. The key may be not "data" it can be some "xyz". How to achieve that? My expectation is that I should be able to insert data with hardcoding. Please let me know if I am still not clear. Thanks for helping me

Comment: why not receive your key in request as well or configure it in some Database or external configuration file and get the key as per your requirement?